# How to I clone a GitHub repo and push it to Gitlab?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-clone, git-remote

I'm trying to clone a github repo, using :

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/.......
```

but I get the error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I'm using the format:

```
$ git remote add <choose a remoteID, not "origin">  <URL to GitLab/GitHub/Atlassian/BitBucket>
```

I've tried using the actual repo ID : using the string in meta content

```
<meta content="123456789" name="octolytics-dimension-repository_id" />
```

In this example, the ID of the repository is `123456789`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in an existing repo ? If not just clone the repo normally using git clone e.g. `git clone https://github.com/openwall/john.git`

You can only add remotes to an existing local repo you have to do `git init` inside a folder to make it a repo first before adding a remote but I'd recommend just cloning it with the command above.